# remove spaces in data plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I want to plot the data without weekends, the main target is only in plotting.

I can't use `resample()` because there is need to dynamically change dataframe from seconds to hours.
Also i tried [this guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_index_formatter2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-date-index-formatter2-py), i putted my values in it and it doesn't work..

`dropna() & isnull()` columns on weeknd got NaN values, and after applying you get a straight line connecting those 2 points, which is not the way i want it.

I've got dataframe:

```
DateTime            Col1     Col2
2019-01-01 22:05:00 1.62684 1.62562
2019-01-01 22:10:00 1.62714 1.62483
2019-01-01 22:15:00 1.62700 1.62573
2019-01-01 22:20:00 1.62700 1.62554
2019-01-01 22:25:00 1.62633 1.62495`
```

Where df is `df = pd.read_csv('first.csv')`

DateTime is `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')`

When i use:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
plt.plot(y.Ask,label=symbList[0])
plt.ylabel('Ask', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('DateTime', fontsize=20)
plt.legend(loc=0, fontsize='xx-large')
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

I recieve data with gaps, those gaps are weekends. My original csv file doesn't contain them, they appear after indexing.

Expected result connect those spaces between data not by straight line, but to remove those weekends from range as well.

Comment: What happens if you use the example from the matplotlib documentation you link to? It should work fine I would think.

Comment: when i apply those method, it's only connect those spaces by straight line, and that is not a result i'm looking for. I want to split those spaces, not just connecting it by line @ImportanceOfBeingErnest